# Is there any Js event or function which fires or executes before any action?

Tags: javascript, jquery

As there is a directive in `AngularJs` - `onLocationChange()` and `C#` has `onActionExecute()`, is there any event like these in Javascript which executes just before any action within the entire website.

Comment: What do you mean by "any action"?

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer : I want it to excute before any ajax and location change.

Comment: @VikashVerma - This has your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177233/javascript-event-that-runs-before-page-changes

Comment: You would need to write your own for before an Ajax call. Nothing like that exists out of the box. But if you don't want to write your own jQuery supports events that kick off before an Ajax call. As for when location changes I think I have read `beforeunload` is very unreliable.

Comment: @AtheistP3ace : Is not any common event?

Comment: Like a `onUserThought` event, or perhaps `onPrecog`?

Comment: something like that.....but action instead of thought.

Comment: @VikashVerma I am not sure I understand the question. There is no common event for before an Ajax call unless you are using jQuery. Then you would use `ajaxStart`. As for a common event to use before you move to a new page it is `beforeunload` but I have read that is not reliable since you can't guarantee it will be called or the code will complete before the page unloads.

Answer (score 0):

from your question it seems like you want to observe user navigation i.e: when ever address bar location gets changed.

You can use an older method detecting whenever page gets refresh

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
    // perform  something here
}, false);
```

for SPAs (Single page applications you can use hashchange

```
//detecting hashchange
window.onhashchange = function() { 
     //code  
}
```