# Run JavaScript after every page load

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, webdriver, selenide

I am using [Selenide](https://selenide.org/) to test a website. 
I need some event listeners set up on every page.
To do so I need some kind of page load event that tells me whenever Selenium is loading a new page.

A possible (but ugly) solution would be checking the current url in a loop every x seconds.

---

## Solution:

```
WebDriverRunner.addListener(new WebDriverEventListener() {
    private String urlBeforeClick;

    @Override
    public void afterNavigateTo(String s, WebDriver webDriver) {
        // code here
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeClickOn(WebElement webElement, WebDriver webDriver) {
        this.urlBeforeClick = webDriver.getCurrentUrl();
    }

    @Override
    public void afterClickOn(WebElement webElement, WebDriver webDriver) {
        // if the url is different after a click a new page was loaded.
        if (!Objects.equals(this.urlBeforeClick, webDriver.getCurrentUrl()))
            // code here
    }
});
```

---

**Note:** I dont think this is should be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: No, I dont want to know when a page has finished loading. I want to be notified whenever a page is being loaded.

Comment: Then you probably want to use the `ready` event instead of the `onload` event. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready.

Comment: No, I want to be notified whenever selenium loads starts to load a new page, not when a particular page is fully loaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm coming from C# so I don't know the exact code but you still should be able to wrap your WebDriver in [EventFiringWebDriver](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/events/EventFiringWebDriver.html) and use beforeNavigateTo. Which according to that link is available in java as well.

**Edit:** As pointed out in the comments beforeNavigateTo only fires when directly sending the navigate command to the driver. Instead listen to EventClicking & ElementClicked events, cache the current URL on the clicking event and then check if it has changed on the clicked event.

Comment: This works for page navigation I do from java, but not when a link is clicked on the page

Comment: That's right, I forgot that does not get triggered. I pulled up some old code and found what I did was listen to the EventClicking & ElementClicked events, cache the current URL on the clicking event and then check if it has changed on the clicked event.

Answer (score 1):

This page talks about an "unload" event. Could this work for you?

[Javascript event that runs before page changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177233/javascript-event-that-runs-before-page-changes)

I also found that an anonymous function in the page will run before the onLoad event.
https://jsfiddle.net/pawqhdjy/

```
function codeAddress() {
    alert('second');
}

window.onload = codeAddress;

(function () {
    alert("first");
})();
```

Comment: THe unload event does no help me as I need to execute js on the new page. The load event also does not work for me as cant know when to attach the listener